# マルチプレクサが一定の値しか送信しなくなりました

Tags: arduino, esp32, i2c

使用機器
・ESP32 DevKitC
・TCA9548A I2C Multiplexer
・MPU6050

tca9548aを使用したところ、値が全て15163になります。
センサを取り外しても値は送られるため、センサの問題では無いと思われます。
tca9548aのA0,A1,A2ピンはgndに接続しているためtca9548aのアドレスは0x70のはずです。
コードはほとんどコピペです。

画像は回路

[image]

```c
#include <Wire.h>

int16_t axRaw, ayRaw, azRaw, gxRaw, gyRaw, gzRaw, GyroX, GyroY, GyroZ, sensor, temperature;

void TCA9548A(uint8_t bus){
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x70);
  Wire.write(1 << bus);    
}

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Wire.setClock(400000);
  Wire.begin();

  Wire.beginTransmission(0x70);
  Wire.write(0x6B);
  Wire.write(0x00);
  Wire.endTransmission(); 
//加速度初期設定
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x70);
  Wire.write(0x1C);
  Wire.write(0x10);
  Wire.endTransmission();
//ジャイロ初期設定
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x70);
  Wire.write(0x1B);
  Wire.write(0x08);
  Wire.endTransmission();
//LPF設定
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x70);
  Wire.write(0x1A);
  Wire.write(0x05);
  Wire.endTransmission();
}

void loop() {
  for(sensor = 2; sensor < 4; sensor++){
  TCA9548A(sensor);
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x70);
  Wire.write(0x3B);
  Wire.endTransmission();
  Wire.requestFrom(0x70, 14);
  while (Wire.available() < 14);
  axRaw = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read();
  ayRaw = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read();
  azRaw = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read();
  temperature = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read();
  gxRaw = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read();
  gyRaw = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read();
  gzRaw = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read();

    Serial.print(axRaw/1638400.0); Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(ayRaw/1638400.0); Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(azRaw/1638400.0); Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(gxRaw/131.0); Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(gyRaw/131.0); Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(gzRaw/131.0);
      
  }
  Serial.println("");
  delay(100);
}
```

Comment: MPU-6050は24ピンのICです。図を見ると4ピンx4です。何かしらモジュールを使っていると思いますが何を使っていますか?

Comment: 図にI2Cのプルアップ抵抗が見当たりません。省略しているだけですか?